# I can't use Storage from @angular/fire for some reason (ANGULAR 16)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

i'm kinda new to angular/fire and i was trying to create a basic app trying some of it's features. Firestore and auth seems to work fine, but when i try to inject Storage, angular drops me this error:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).

And tbh, i didn't find anything helpful.

Here's my app.module.ts and my app.component.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FindMATCHComponent } from './find-match/find-match.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAnalytics,getAnalytics,ScreenTrackingService,UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore,getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FindMATCHComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() =>  initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
  ],
  providers: [
    ScreenTrackingService,UserTrackingService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
import { Firestore, collection, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { getDownloadURL, ref, Storage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
...
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'classicgwentonline-bcde8';
  firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore)
  items$: Observable<any[]>;
  private storage: Storage = inject(Storage);
  constructor() {
    const aCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'items')
    this.items$ = collectionData(aCollection);

  }

}
```

I just expected that storage API would work as firestore and auth, but as soon as i inject cloud storage, angular says that i didn't call initializeApp().

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue with changing the imports in app.module.ts like this:

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)), 
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
        StorageModule,
        ....// other imports
    ],
```

Imported from:

```
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { StorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
```

Seems to be working for now. I hope to be of help. Spent all day trying to make it work... after all StorageModule was the key!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular-fire v16 has just [reached RC](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/releases/tag/16.0.0-rc.0) !

You can install it with `npm install @angular/fire@16.0.0-rc.0`

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem using "firebase": "^9.6.0", and "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0" with Angular 16.

I hope it helps you!.

Comment: I tried it, still not working, it's really weird

Comment: You can try this on AppModule file.
 provideStorage(() => getStorage(getApp())),

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Having the same problem on angular 16. Are there any updates? Thanks!