# I'm having an error when trying to use angular fire storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I already have firestore, auth, and storage provided in app.module and i'm able to use firestore and auth no problem. The problem occurs when I add the storage to the constructor of my service. For some reason, it cannot find the initialized app though I already have it above the provideStorage in my module. Here's the error I'm getting.

```
main.ts:6 ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (index.esm2017.js:479:29)
    at getStorage (index.esm2017.js:3560:33)
    at angular-fire.js:227:48
    at angular-fire.js:160:59
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:27349:28)
    at runOutsideAngular (angular-fire.js:160:35)
    at angular-fire.js:227:21
    at app.module.ts:57:36
```

Here's my module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage())
  ],
  providers: [{provide: MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: globalRippleConfig}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I already tried to delete node_module then reinstall all packages.

Comment: I found simmilar question with answer of using STORAGEMODULE on app.module.ts. but when i try to use ref function to get the refrence to the storage it says cant read properties of null, i have no idea how to solve that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693349/i-cant-use-storage-from-angular-fire-for-some-reason-angular-16?rq=2